# What is the basic difference between Arch and Gentoo Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, gentoo

What is the difference between Arch Linux and Gentoo Linux? Their ideologies seem quite similar to me.

Comment: Hi Ritik, welcome to unix.SE.  This question is not a good format for this site because it's quite broad and primarily opinion based.  Can narrow down your question at all?  Is there a particular component of their ideologies that you expect to be different but seem similar?

Comment: The similarity I meant was that both are built by the users according to their wish.

Comment: The means by which the user goes about it is one major difference.  In this sense, Arch is more normative by comparison to other distros, I think.  Gentoo might be a bit opaque for people who haven't used a compiler much, leading to some [perverse interpretations ;D](http://funroll-loops.info/) of its purpose.

Comment: Gentoo will allow you to manage the packages' features you want with [USE flags](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=2&chap=2). The _portage_ package manager is a masterpiece. But you will need time and it will be a major difference between the 2 distros. When you pull in particular `gcc` you will know. I have never seen a process where a beginner such as myself could compile/install 1500 packages with no errors, including gcc, webkit and Libreoffice(full). Also, the Gentoo Handbook has the most detailed install walkthrough I have ever seen. I use Arch - basmati rice;-)

Comment: Why closing the question ? I don't agree this is opinion-based. Asking for differences is not asking for opinions.

Comment: @JohanBoulé - Asking for differences is basically courting for opinions   That said completely agree, it should be possible to post a table of like-for-like comparison -  marked as community wiki, would allow individual preference and bias to drive continual editing, yielding a very high quality answer.

Comment: What qualifies as a "basic" difference? Without that being clarified, it makes no sense for this to be reopened or even being kept on this site.

Comment: This question is not opinion based

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Yes, the distros are of similar, with both being set to satisfy more experienced users, and both aim to be fast and highly customizable. The most technical similarity is that both are based upon the Linux Kernel.

While most functions may seem similar, the two are different in many ways.

1. Apparently, Gentoo documentation is said to be very intimidating to new users, while Arch documentation is very much up to the KISS (Keep it simple, stupid) motto.
2. Package managers are also different. Arch Linux uses the Pacman (or in some spins, such as antergos, Pacman XG) which uses the good **precompiled package system** while Gentoo uses the Portage manager which makes **packages from source code**.

   With the difference in package managers one distribution may have fewer packages readied than the other. I would say that Arch would have a larger selection of packages compared to Gentoo, while Gentoo allows fine-grained control of specific packages features via [USE flags](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/USE_flag).

   However, most packages are available in source code. So you can fairly easily build them to suit whatever package manager you may be using.

   (If you may be interested, Gentoo's portage manager has many good features not available in the freshly-installed pacman.)
3. **Popularity** is a difference. While you may be interested in being original, the adoption of your OS can make a big difference in your Linux experience. Primarily in how many files you can access out-of-the-disk and how many tutorials you have to look at in times of need.

   According to distrowatch, **Arch Linux is the 8th** in overall popularity, while **Gentoo is at 47th**.

   While popularity may help, this may not help you to easily choose a distro. I haven't personally tried Gentoo, it could just be an amazingly functional and simple OS, while Arch had risen up much further with its head-start.
4. I could list many more differences, but aside from the above (and maybe other) differences, the distributions are quite similar.

If you would like a good resource to make comparisons with, I recommend [distrowatch.com](http://www.distrowatch.com), if you haven't looked at it already.

Comment: Ever since http://wiki.gentoo.org came along, documentation has progressed a lot. Old XML based documentation I believe is being fully phased out.

Comment: Can confirm: Arch docs are phenomenal. I switched to Arch because, in a significant amount of cases, Arch docs would help me solve Ubuntu issues easier than Ubuntu docs would.

Answer (score 21):

Probably the biggest difference is that gentoo provides source packages while arch provides pre compiled binaries. Arch also only supports x86 machines although it has been ported to other architectures with some success. Look [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_compared_to_other_distributions#Gentoo_Linux) for a list.

Answer (score 15):

In the installation of Gentoo, you'll be much more encouraged to compile your own kernel, an experience that any power user of Linux should go through. :)

Arch by default uses systemd for its initialisation. systemd is growing much more popular, and most distributions are moving over to it in place of the old System-V style init system. Gentoo uses this older init system by default, but is aided by OpenRC. Gentoo however does have systemd [available in Portage](http://packages.gentoo.org/package/sys-apps/systemd).

There's one similarity that I'd like to mention though: you can learn a lot about Linux just from *installing* either distribution!

Comment: Hell no, arch installation is a breeze man. Gentoo installation still gives me nightmares (but I love it anyways). Arch installation is literally just partitioning (you can even just make 1 big partition and be done with it), mounting partition, running one (pacstrap) command, setting root password and installing a boot manager. There are a few minor steps inbetween (like locale and whatnot) but I mean it all fits nicely into a small wiki page... Gentoo installation documentation is many, many pages, and it's just that hard too, especially kernel configuration if you want to do it well.

Comment: Gentoo was the first Linux distribution that clicked for me. Prior to that, I had nightmares and hallucinations when I tried Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora I just couldn't understand them, it was so depressing I felt like an idiot. But when I read and followed the Gentoo handbook, it was the most honest and clearest explanation and opened my eyes to Linux.

Comment: @Cestarian kernel config is easy if you know what to do, but still very time consuming

Comment: @glibg10b easy to do maybe, harder to learn, and quite difficult to master.